# How to set KDE desktop wallpaper to colour programmatically?

Tags: linux, opensuse, kde-plasma-5, desktop-environments, kde-plasma-workspace

Like [How to set KDE desktop wallpaper from command line?](https://superuser.com/q/488232/904401):

> How do I set the KDE desktop wallpaper to a `.JPEG` file from the command line?

...except that I want to set it to a colour rather than an image, as:

1. > [image]
2. > [image]

...allows.

Comment: I ask because of https://github.com/oskarsh/Yin-Yang/issues/246#issuecomment-1837211935.